# Which network command does all the thing a windows restart would do?

Tags: windows, networking, diagnostic

**Specification** : 64 bit Windows, Core 2 Duo

Network components used :

- **Wifi** - Intel 5100 AGN
- **Datacard** - NDIS based - Huawei 3g

Issue when using Wifi :

- Every 15 minutes, internet connection gets lost for about 10
  seconds(It is confirmed this is due to the ISP.  The data lines have
  issues and periodic issues keep happening.).  Then everything is
  clear from ISP end.  But chrome and firefox cannot resolve the tlds.
- Restart is done.  No changes are made to the modem and router.  But
  now, chrome and firefox resumes resolving the tld.

  In the above scneario, **if** I plug in my **data card**, everything **works**.  Chrome and firefox detects this is a new network, a new ip and things work **fine**.

**What** has changed now?  Is there any **windows command** I can execute that will do all the **things** which a **restart** does for network.

My **diagnosis** :
Once chrome and firefox understands network is down, it **assumes** things wont work on the same network.  The **cache** of DNS used by these browsers causes some kind of issues.

Answer (score 1):

Check your router's DHCP server lease time.   When your DHCP lease expires, windows 'hiccups' during the renew lease phase.  Some routers have ridiculously low lease times (yes, I've seen 15 minutes!).

Your datacard (3G) likely has a 24 hour lease, which is typical, so you're not seeing the issue.

Evidently, windows drops the connection and requests a new lease... rather than requesting a new lease and (if needed!) dropping/reconfiguring the connection. {Sigh}

If this is your issue, another caveat is to NOT set the lease time to 'infinite/indefinite/unlimited', as the value used is occasionally seen by windows as '-1' seconds (guess what value is used for unlimited lease?), and 'now + (-1)' seconds means the lease expires immediately.

An arbitrarily long value like 6.8 days is recommended, not whole days either, to try to mitigate the 'it always dies at 2pm on sunday' kind of things.  Besides, if it were predictable, you'd get frustrated... random hiccups on windows are acceptable. (right? gotta love BSOD's!)

Silly Windows!  Standards are for following!

Answer (score 1):

In the 'network connections' control panel try right clicking on the connection and disabling it, then re enabling it.  This often works for me, though for some problems a restart of the computer seems to be the only cure.

I'd imagine there is some way to script this, so the hardware can be restarted automatically or with a simple command.